# 2002 Honda Civic Overheating

Tags: honda, civic, overheating

So the first time the car overheated it was basically out of water. I had recently obtained the car for temporary use from a friend and hadn't seen any issues up to that point. I did smell a weird smell that I thought was from a burning of some sort of chemical. Not oil for sure but I have come to the conclusion it's antifreeze. I have also still come to the conclusion it is due to a slow leak somewhere.

After filling the water I didn't have overheating probelms doe a while but I was still getting the smell when driving it. I have watched the water level closely and started trying to figure out what's going on. Recently it's started over heating and today finally it's just done. I really am stumped and it's frustrating me. I know there is a  leak of some sort and there is no pressure that I can tell, or very little, so I am assuming there is no water flowing through the engine. I am thinking it might be the water pump now but it's just weird how it's led up to this over a period of about 4 months. Normally when a water pump goes out it goes out. I am not loosing all the water or even a ton out of the radiator bit again no pressure in the hoses. Top hose never seems barely warm. I guess I haven't chececk that on the bottom. I have repeatedly seen a great splash and leak on the radiator and grille when it over heats. I've replaced the radiator cap just to make sure. I really don't think it's the thermostat due to the whole ordeal. I haven't been able to get the car jacked up to check the bypass hose. I'm just looking for more ideas. Thought it might also have a leak at the over flow or over flow hoses.  It is now just over heating with no pressure in the radiator.

Help? What have I missed? :)
Thanks,
Thrill

Comment: Welcome to the site and some great sleuthing going on here! I would suggest the reason you aren't getting pressure is *the cooling system is leaking*, which would not allow the pressure to build. The problem lies in the fact you haven't been able to discern where. A couple of questions: If you smell the exhaust does it smell sweet? If so, the engine is burning the coolant. Pull the dipstick and look at the oil. Does it look like chocolate milk? If so, there's a leak of coolant getting into the oil. Place a clean piece of cardboard under the engine. A leak may show itself that way.

Comment: Oil is good. Did check that. Ty, forgot about the cardboard solution to see what's leaking. I know there is a leak. I just still haven't pin pointed where like you said. I will keep exploring